# No Spring AOP Proxy on windows jvm for particular class

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am facing a strange and frustrating problem: On my developer station a single Spring Bean is not accessed through a proxy to be enhanced by AOP. In the debugger you can see that there is no proxy used but the actual bean.

The frustrating part is the fact that (most (only one)) other coworkers have no problem. And running on a unix machine is also fine. Only my setup is somehow strange.

I changed the underlying tomcat (8.5, 9.0.12/14). I used different JDKs/JVMs (8.*, 11.*).

The Bean is annotated with @Service like all other beans, which are working fine.
On startup of the server I can see a "huge" stack when the "bad" bean is instantiated. I somehow suspect circular stuff spring is doing to instantiate this service bean.
The following excerpt is only a small part. It repeats about 10+ times before the bean (the constructor) is acutally called. Other service beans a "directly" instantiated.

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).createBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 498
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).lambda$doGetBean$0(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 320
522264438.getObject() line: not available
DefaultListableBeanFactory(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry).getSingleton(String, ObjectFactory<?>) line: 222
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).doGetBean(String, Class<T>, Object[], boolean) line: 318
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).getBean(String) line: 199
DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(String) line: not available
ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 391
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 1288
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).createBeanInstance(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 1127
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).doCreateBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 538
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).createBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 498
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).lambda$doGetBean$0(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 320
522264438.getObject() line: not available
DefaultListableBeanFactory(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry).getSingleton(String, ObjectFactory<?>) line: 222
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).doGetBean(String, Class<T>, Object[], boolean) line: 318
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).getBean(String, Class<T>) line: 204
DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(String, Class) line: not available
PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory, AbstractApplicationContext) line: 228
XmlWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).registerBeanPostProcessors(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) line: 707
XmlWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).refresh() line: 531
```

Any ideas/hints why this bean may act so strange?

Comment: I think you cannot expect any meaningful answers with this kind of question here, only wild guesses at best. Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I was expecting wild guesses. If there was a reproducible way, I may have got it myself ;). Well there is probably one, but how to pin point it is the actual question here.

Comment: Well, you could just start by reducing your project to the smallest version still showing that behaviour and sharing it inclusive Maven POM on GitHub. Error log snippets without any code are simply useless. And if you were expecting wild guesses, then - with all due respect - maybe a discussion forum would be better suited for your question than SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Spring-Component had the annotation `@EnableAsync`. That little thing creates a proxy which prevented the actually needed/wanted proxy (aspect).